# Perforce trigger for xml validation

Tags: xml, validation, perforce

I'm trying to set up a perforce trigger to run and validate xml file on submit to prevent simple invalid xml problems.

I'm trying to figure out what p4 commands need to be run by the trigger by testing them out in console before writing code. I have a simple changelist, 12345, that contains a text file with a single line change. I would like to be able to print the entire file to a string and then convert it to xml for validation.

My problem is that, at least running in console, the command p4 print file.txt@12345, p4 print file.txt@=12345, etc. all appear to be printing the committed file in the depot, not what is in the pending changelist.

Maybe this will change depending on the type of trigger, change-submit/change-content, but I would really like to get this squared away before investing time to create the trigger script.

Has anyone else done this? How can I get this to look at the uncommitted changelist instead of the depot head?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger needs to be executed as a `change-content` trigger, not `change-submit` (which will run during the first phase of the submit, before the file content is available on the server).

To test your trigger, use a shelved changelist, and run commands of the form `p4 print @=CHANGE`.  During a `change-content` trigger the changelist is for most practical purposes in a "shelved" state and the content is available via the same `@=` syntax that works on shelves.